# Simulation of beam propagation with mirrors and lenses

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform

I like to simulate the propagation of the wave front of an arbitrary 2d electric field. The free space propagation can be modeled in the paraxial approximation via the Fresnel equation using Fourier transforms (as been dealt with in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129761/modeling-the-free-space-propagation-of-laser-beams-using-fourier-transforms)). However, I also want the field passing mirrors and lenses. How do I do this? Is it just applying a phase corresponding to the curvature of the mirror or lens?

Comment: I don't know if it contains also the solution about mirrors, but in Goodman's "Introduction to Fourier Optics" there should a solution, in the same approximation, for lenses.